# Getting a <td>'s height and a <p>'s font size with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I get and set a `<td>`'s height and a `<p>`'s CSS property *font-size* with JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var h = $('td').height();
$('p').css('font-size', '12pt');
```

www.jquery.com

Comment: Why would this work (i.e. answer Pieters question)? Does [$('td')] make any sense? Doesn't the .css method only SET the font size? Did Pieter ask for a jquery answer? Not so great an answer, I would say, sorry.

Comment: jQuery is a *javascript* library.  he didn't say he wanted them both set and retrieved in one go, mr. smarty.

Comment: well, the question starts with: "How can I get and set..."

Comment: funny, this answer, although accepted by the question poster and thus presumably correct, has so far yielded +3/-3.  i don't mind the downvotes, but would the (future) downvoters please state their reasons?